# c3.js how to place the y label inside the bar in a horizontal bar graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, c3.js

I am working on a horizontal bar graph and the y-labels are a bit long(they take up half the space in mobile view).

I want to know if it is possible to shift the labels inside the bars.

This is what I have
[image]

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#IndivisualScore',
                bar: {
                    width: 15,
                    space: 2
                },
                padding: {
                    left: 100
                },
                color: {
                    pattern: ['#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62' ]
                },
                data: {
                    x: 'x',
                    columns:
                        [
                      ['x', "Initiative", "Sees and Acts on opportunities", "Persistence", "Information seeking", "Concern for high Quality of work","Commitment to Work Contract","Efficiency Orientation","Systematic Planning","Problem Solving","Self-confidence","Assertiveness","Persuasion","Use of influence Strategies"],
                      ['value', 300, 400,245,342,532,213,452,344,123,533,234,231,324]
                      ],

                    type: 'bar',
                    color: function(inColor, data) {
                        var colors = ['#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62', '#ACB6DD','#FABF62' ];
                        if(data.index !== undefined) {
                            return colors[data.index];
                        }

                        return inColor;
                    },
                    labels: true
                },
                axis: {
                    rotated: true,
                    x: {
                        type: 'category'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    grouped: true
                },
                legend: {
                    show: true
                }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="IndivisualScore"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic solution is to apply transform to all labels:

```
.c3-text {
    transform: translateX(-25px);
    fill: #000 !important; /* to make them visible */
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/30zg9vot/3/).

More advanced solution could be to measure width of every label and set *translateX* values individually.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i was looking for this https://jsbin.com/sexahopeko/edit?html,js,output.